# Want to add a order line item column in the admin panel order view page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order, admin-panel, sales-order-view

I need to add the additional column in the table the field is already in the table i don't want to create it. Field name in table is **additional_data** in **sales_order_item** table. The below showed image is admin panel order items listing image.

**Now the line items showing** 
[image: Order Line item]

**Need Output as**
[image: Order Line item need to show]

After updating with below answer with my coulumn name Tax code and added the block tax_code.phtml

**In sales_order_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs" name="sales_order_tabs">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" name="order_tab_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/tab/info.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Messages" name="order_messages"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml">
                        <container name="extra_customer_info"/>
                    </block>
                    <container name="order_additional_info"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                                <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                                <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
                                <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                                <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                                <item name="taxcode" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Code</item>
                                <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                                <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                                <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                                <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" name="default_order_items_renderer" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                                    <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                                    <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                                    <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                                    <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                                    <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                                    <item name="taxcode" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-taxcode</item>
                                    <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                                    <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                                    <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                                    <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                                </argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="tax_code" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/tax_code.phtml" group="column" />

                    </block>

                    <container name="payment_additional_info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="order-payment-additional" />
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Payment" name="order_payment"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History" name="order_history" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/history.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="gift_options" template="Magento_Sales::order/giftoptions.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Giftmessage" name="order_giftmessage" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/giftmessage.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals/tax.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_info</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">order_tab_info</argument>
                </action>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices" name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_invoices</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_invoice.grid.container</argument>
                </action>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos" name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_creditmemos</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container</argument>
                </action>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments" name="sales_order_shipment.grid.container"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_shipments</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_shipment.grid.container</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History</argument>
                </action>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions" name="sales_transactions.grid.container"/>
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_transactions</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_transactions.grid.container</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

**In template/items/columns/tax_code.phtml**

```
<span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __($block->getItem()->getData('additional_data')) ?></span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update your layout file (overrite defaul.phml)**

```
<referenceContainer name="left">
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs" name="sales_order_tabs">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" name="order_tab_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/tab/info.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Messages" name="order_messages"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" name="order_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml">
                <container name="extra_customer_info"/>
            </block>
            <container name="order_additional_info"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                        <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                        <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item>
                        <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                        <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                        <item name="additional-data" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Code</item>
                        <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                        <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                        <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                        <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" name="default_order_items_renderer" template="VendoreName_ModuleNaem::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml"><!-- here add your module name -->
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                            <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item>
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                            <item name="additional-data" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-taxcode</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="tax_code" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/tax_code.phtml" group="column" />

            </block>

            <container name="payment_additional_info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="order-payment-additional" />
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Payment" name="order_payment"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History" name="order_history" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/history.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="gift_options" template="Magento_Sales::order/giftoptions.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Giftmessage" name="order_giftmessage" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/giftmessage.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals/tax.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_info</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">order_tab_info</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Invoices" name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_invoices</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_invoice.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos" name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_creditmemos</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Shipments" name="sales_order_shipment.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_shipments</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_shipment.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\History</argument>
        </action>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Transactions" name="sales_transactions.grid.container"/>
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_transactions</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_transactions.grid.container</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

> **After that add this file in your module**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleNaem/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer**

**default.phtml**

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<tr>
    <?php $i = 0;
    $columns = $block->getColumns();
    $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass) : ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <td class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '') ?>">
            <?= $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?>
            <?php
                if ($columnName == "additional-data") {
                    echo $_item->getAdditionalData();
                }

            ?>
        </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 3):

You need to add/create 'sales_order_view.xml' file in your custom module (please create if not exist any) at below path:

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

In this file you need to put below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tabs" name="sales_order_tabs">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Info" name="order_tab_info" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/tab/info.phtml">        
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="column_name" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Column</item>
                            </argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="my_column" template="Namespace_Modulename::mycolumn.phtml" group="column"/> 
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then, you need to create **mycolumn.phtml** file at below path:

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/templates/mycolumn.phtml

In **mycolumn.phtml** file you can put code like below:

```
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()) : ?>
     <div class="admin__field">
            <div class="admin__field">
                 <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __($_item->getAdditionalData()) ?></span>
           </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's it! Please check and let me know if you need any further help.

Happy to help!

Thanks,

Comment: I updated my answer Mr.@Pratik Navapara please check and update it

Comment: @Sabareesh, please check my updated code added in 'mycolumn.phtml' fiie.

Comment: @Sabareesh, I hope my answer helped you to achieve your needs. Please upvote my answer if it really helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how my column and phtml will combine @pratik Navapara

Comment: @Sabareesh, you can please check xml file code I have given. In that file you can check relation.